# Uncaught Error: undefined is not function (near '...(0,_resolveAssetSource2.setCustomTransformer))

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Getting error after expo start for android

[image]

Comment: Does it look normal when Ios?

Comment: Could you please provide more code which is producing that screen?

Comment: @hongdevelop - Same issue for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with expo-asset.

I removed this chunk of code from expo-asset/build/Asset.js from node_modules.

```
// Override React Native's asset resolution for `Image` components
setCustomSourceTransformer(resolver => {
    try {
        const asset = Asset.fromMetadata(resolver.asset);
        return resolver.fromSource(asset.downloaded ? asset.localUri : asset.uri);
    }
    catch (e) {
        return resolver.defaultAsset();
    }
});
```

Not a great solution but it gets the app to run =(

I only started getting this error after upgrading to Expo SDK 33.